# How to expand rows in a tibble based on a list of values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this row

```
  first coor  second
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 first ALL   second
```

I want to expand this row into multiple rows and replace the coor column based on the following values

```
coor = c("ESP", "FRA", "GER")
```

So that I get this in the end

```
  first coor  second
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 first ESP   second
2 first FRA   second
3 first GER   second
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We may create a `list` column and `unnest` it

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
    mutate(coor = list(.env$coor)) %>% 
    unnest(coor)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  first coor  second
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 first ESP   second
2 first FRA   second
3 first GER   second
```

---

Or another option is `crossing` on the subset of data with 'coor' vector

```
crossing(dat %>%
           select(-coor), coor)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  first second coor 
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 first second ESP  
2 first second FRA  
3 first second GER
```

#### data

```
dat <- tibble(first = "first", coor = "ALL", second = "second")
coor <- c("ESP", "FRA", "GER")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

1. Rename the vector
2. use `slice` to expand dataframe to the length of vector
3. fill `coor` with vector

```
library(dplyr)

vec_coor <- coor

dat %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = length(vec_coor))) %>% 
  mutate(coor = vec_coor)
```

```
 first coor  second
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 first ESP   second
2 first FRA   second
3 first GER   second
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. We can create a lookup table and apply `full_join`. `dat` and `coor` are from akrun's answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

lookup <- data.table(
  coor = rep("ALL", length(coor)),
  coor_new = coor
)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  full_join(lookup, by = "coor") %>%
  select(first, coor = coor_new, second)

dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   first coor  second
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> 
# 1 first ESP   second
# 2 first FRA   second
# 3 first GER   second
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             first = c("first"),
              coor = c("ALL"),
            second = c("second")
      )

df %>% 
  complete(first, coor=c("ESP", "FRA", "GER"), second) %>% filter(!coor == "ALL")

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   first coor  second
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 first ESP   second
#> 2 first FRA   second
#> 3 first GER   second
```